# Arch linux boots into graphical bug with no console access (ATI card)

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, arch-linux, amd-radeon

I installed Arch with gnome 3 yesterday and all was going well. I installed open source video drivers for my card (Radeon HD7770) however the performance was really bad (I could hear my GFX card fan going crazy just from showing the DE) so I uninstalled the driver intending to give the proprietary one a try.

Now what happens is when I boot arch I get the regular console messages until when I assume it would ask me to login. Then the screen is frozen with artifacting across the top 1/3 of the screen. I can't do anything with the console, I've tried blindly logging in and typing reboot but this doesn't do anything.

Anyone have an idea of how I can fix this or somehow get console access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access GRUB, you can try to change your boot entry by adding `3` at the end, like this :

```
 kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/..ro 3
```

This will [boot your system without launching X server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Recovery:_disabling_Xorg_before_GUI_login), leaving you with a TTY. You'll then be able to login and revert back to open source drivers, or troubleshoot your installation by looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: After 5 minutes I got a bit impatient and decided to just reinstall arch... I'm sure this will come in handy some other time though, thanks.

Comment: Well after reinstalling I did it to myself again, apparently it's the vesa drivers causing the issues as I tried to boot gnome with only those installed. Your fix gave me access to the console after deleting "quiet" from the end of that line, thanks again.